# logger print error: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to fix a "logger print error: not enough arguments for format string" cropping up on a jupyter lab report and have tried a few solutions but no joy.

my dataframe looks like this:

```python
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10'])
```

```python
#I'm applying a % format because I only need last four columns in percentage:
df_1['col7'] = df_1['col7'].apply("{0:.0f}%".format)
df_1['col8'] = df_1['col8'].apply("{0:.0f}%".format)
df_1['col9'] = df_1['col9'].apply("{0:.0f}%".format)
df_1['col10'] = df_1['col10'].apply("{0:.0f}%".format)
```

I want to maintain the table format/structure so i'm not doing print(df_1) but rather just:

```python
df_1
```

The above works fine, but I can't seem to get past the "logger print error: not enough arguments for format string" error.

p.s I've also tried using formats like "{:.2%}" or "{0:.0%}" but it turns -3 to -300%

Here is what the columns look like without any format:

[image]

Edit: fixed by removing this line from dataframe source query '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: .format(???) you need to pass the arguments into the brackets

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 3, this should do it:

```
from random import randint

df_1['col7'] = df_1['col7'].apply(f"{randint(-3,-301)}%")
df_1['col8'] = df_1['col8'].apply(f"{randint(-3,-301)}%")
df_1['col9'] = df_1['col9'].apply(f"{randint(-3,-301)}%")
df_1['col10'] = df_1['col10'].apply(f"{randint(-3,-301)}%")
```

Comment: indeed using python 3. The above change came back with "AttributeError: '0%' is not a valid function for 'Series' object"

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you want to format in?

Comment: I just want to change the int values from df_1['col7'] etc from -3 to -3% or -3.00%

Comment: So -3 to -3% is -300% to -3%?

Comment: actually no, but I've just found the reason for the error was because I'm using '%Y-%m-%d' in the query loading the dataframe .. /facepalm hmm so separate issue now it seems

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?

Comment: I'm good now - I think the logger error was a bit ambiguous as I had to remove '%Y-%m-%d' from the sql query powering the dataframe